# What is the normal timeline between verbal offer and written offer?

Tags: united-states, faculty-application, tenure-track

So I was offered a tenure track verbally. I am going to accept this offer next week verbally. Because I asked for a week to think about this.

So I was wondering how long it can take to get the written offer signed by the provost or president may be.

I know it varies depending on the university. But I just want to get an idea

Comment: This is completely variable and depends very highly on the college/university and how it operates.  Ask the person with whom you have been discussing the offer, not us.

Comment: I asked just to get an idea

Comment: Somewhere between a day and a year? But, I'm guessing that's not very helpful. More useful to ask the people who can give a better answer, like AlexanderWoo suggests.